# Wiring a pull switch ceiling fan (with light) to a wall switch

Tags: electrical, wiring

If I am wiring an existing ceiling fan with a light that is currently controlled by a pull chain switch for light and fan speed to a wall switch, and I'd like to use 14/4 AWG (with ground) wire to do so, where can I buy such wire?  I'd like to avoid buying a roll of 250 feet of it - which is the only length I can seem to find at hardware stores and online at the moment.  I know running 14/2/2 would also work, but I can't find a means to buy that wire by the foot or in any length shorter than 250 feet either. Thanks!

Comment: The big box stores usually have 50' packages of wire or you can purchase by the foot.

Comment: Call around to a bona-fide electrical supply house and they will happily stock and sell you whatever you need by-the-foot.  If they don't, they're a *terrible* supply house.  Speaking of terrible, don't just go to a local big-box store. Their selection is awful, their support is worse, and their prices are not nearly as good as they want you to think. The only way they continue to exist in the electrical-supply game is by hoodwinking people like you into thinking they're the only game in town.